# VS Code Auto-Formatter Automatically Adds Lines Between Comments and Class

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, format, comments, code-formatting

**Windows 10**
vscode : **v1.51.0**
Beautify : **v1.5.0**

`Python Auto Formatter` in vs code adds these Lines in-between between comment and class.
When this is done between classes its fine, but when I want to add a description of 
a class above it using a comment, it again puts 2 lines between the comment and the class

Code Before Saving :

```
class Hello():
    def ok():
        pass

# ok
class Hi():

    def ok():
        pass
```

Code After Saving :

```
class Hello():
    def ok():
        pass

# ok


class Hi():

    def ok():
        pass
```

Vscode `Settings.json` :

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Signed Dark Pro",
    "editor.fontSize": 16,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "window.zoomLevel": 2,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "[jsonc]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "HookyQR.beautify"
    },
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "files.autoSave": "off",
    "python.jediEnabled": false,
    "python.languageServer": "Microsoft",
    "todo-tree.tree.showScanModeButton": false,
    "todo-tree.highlights.defaultHighlight": {
        "icon": "alert",
        "type": "text",
        "foreground": "black",
        "background": "#FF8C00",
        "opacity": 100,
        "iconColour": "#FF8C00"
    },
    "todo-tree.highlights.customHighlight": {
        "TODO": {
            "icon": "check",
            "gutterIcon": true,
            "type": "text-and-comment"
        },
        "FIXME": {
            "foreground": "#AACCFF",
            "background": "#222333",
            "iconColour": "yellow",
            "gutterIcon": true,
            "type": "text-and-comment"
        },
        "COMMENT": {
            "foreground": "red",
            "background": "blue",
            "iconColour": "red",
            "gutterIcon": true,
            "type": "text-and-comment"
        }
    },
    "kite.showWelcomeNotificationOnStartup": false,
    "python.pythonPath": "\anaconda3\\envs\\tf-gpu\\python.exe",
    "todo-tree.general.tags": [
        "XXX",
        "TODO",
        "HACK",
        "FIXME",
        "BUG",
        "todo",
        "COMMENT"
    ],
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "java.home": "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-13.0.2",
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.classpath": true,
        "**/.project": true,
        "**/.settings": true,
        "**/.factorypath": true
    },
    "java.refactor.renameFromFileExplorer": "autoApply",
    "java.project.importOnFirstTimeStartup": "automatic",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "diffEditor.codeLens": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you used `"editor.formatOnSave": true,` in the settings. For the problem you described, it is recommended that you add the following settings to work with it:

```
 "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modifications",
```

Before and after saving (formatting) the file:

[image]